# How to close the Spring ApplicationContext but don't stop the JMS Listener to avoid the "Resource leak: 'context' is never closed"?

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks

I want to close the Spring ApplicationContext to avoid the "Resource leak: 'context' is never closed" warning. But When I close it, the DefaultJMSListenerContainer is closed too. Therefore I can no longer receive any message. My question is can I close the ApplicationContext, but leave the JMSListenerContainer alive?

The JMSListenerContainer is like below:

```
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">  
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />  
    <property name="destination" ref="topicDestination" />  
    <property name="messageListener" ref="clientMessageListener" />  
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you update question with JMSListenerContainer configuration?

Comment: @Evgeny I added the JmsListenerContainer, you can refer it and give me the suggestions. The MessageContainer can work if I don't call the close method of the AbstractApplicationContext. But if I call it, the MessageListenerContainer will be closed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JMSListenerContainer is a part of application context you can't just close ApplicationContext and continue receiving messages. Your app requires context to operate.

So I see two options here:

1. Ignore warning “Resource leak: 'context' is never closed” or supress it with `@SuppressWarnings("resource")`. Resources will be freed anyway when jvm terminates. So you don't do anything wrong here. 

   Also you can add shutdown hook `((AbstractApplicationContext)context).registerShutdownHook();` to be sure that spring context will be gracefully closed on jvw shutdowm.
2. Use following construction to create context

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       //try with resources guarantees that context will be closed
       try(AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml")){

           //some code...

           //will wait any input in console to avoid immediate context closing
           System.in.read();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your warming heat, Evegeny. Both the options can avoid the warnings, but ApplicationContext is not actually closed when the JVM is running. I wonder if this is a true resource leak problem?

Comment: @Linhoo You don't neded to close ApplicationContext while app is running. It is not a resource in general meaning. `AbstractApplicationContext` implements `Closeable` that is why Eclipse shows resource leak warning but in this case it doesn't mean that leak is real.

Comment: The configuration should be resource. Do you know how the ApplicationContext handle it?

Comment: I have another question about it, you can answer it at :[Why I assign the new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(“bean.xml”) to a variable, the resource leak warning gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326348/why-i-assign-the-new-classpathxmlapplicationcontextbean-xml-to-a-variable-t)

Comment: @Linhoo Yes, configuration is resource. However you shouldn't be worried about it as Spring definitely doesn't allow any resource leak inside.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please create two Spring ApplicationContext xml to separate out DefaultJMSListenerContainer from the one Spring ApplicationContext that you are going to close?  Let say create applicationContext-jms.xml for DefaultJMSListenerContainer and create applicationContext.xml for other Spring context configuration. Close the applicationContext.xml to avoid the "Resource leak: 'context' is never closed" warning.

Comment: This will leave the applicationContext-jms not closed. My goal is to avoid all the resource lead warnings, not to close one and open another.

Comment: I have another question about it, you can answer it at :[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326348/why-i-assign-the-new-classpathxmlapplicationcontextbean-xml-to-a-variable-t)

Comment: I have another question about it, you can answer it at :[Why I assign the new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(“bean.xml”) to a variable, the resource leak warning gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326348/why-i-assign-the-new-classpathxmlapplicationcontextbean-xml-to-a-variable-t)